# Passing Data From AppDelegate to View in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to fetch a `JSON` during the launch time and want to use JSON as a resource.

I make request in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and request looking like:

```
NSString *urlAsString = @"myurl";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data is okay. Size: %lu and result: %@", (unsigned long)[data length], responseString);
}
```

It's working well, but I want to pass `data` from MyAppDelegate to `myViewController`. So I will use data with `UILabel`.

What exactly should I do? Is making request in `AppDelegate` wrong?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: making request in app-delegate not good solution. You should make some start-up task that run on background so you will be able to show some spinner to user.
Second: you can store you NSString variable in appDelegate and create getter for it (property). So you can access your App Delegate entity with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Third: You can set it via UIViewController custom constructor or with property.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much. I suppose in this way synch connection blocks current thread and so not to allow using spinner. So can you give any example about start-up task? Is that common name? I've looked around but could'n find any proper answer. Thank you again.

Comment: I mean that you can create your own object that will make request on background and init this object from app delegate class and wait for callback from this object. So you could freeze your application until this task not finished.